# Google Sign-in does nothing when 3rd party cookies are disabled

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-oauth, google-signin

I am using the Google Sign-in Javascript library on my web page that runs on Python on Google App Engine. Everything works fine, unless the user has 3rd party cookies disabled (in Chrome). The signup does open the account chooser (if applicable) and asks for permissions, however after that nothing happens.

On desktop it returns to the signup page and shows following error in the console:

```
Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
```

However I can't detect this error so I can't respond to it either. On mobile, it just gets stuck on a white page. The additional issue here is that since I am asking for offline access, the first signup returns a refresh_token. Due to this error, I never receive this refresh_token.

The error mentioned above shows immediately when I load the page. I would like to detect this, so that I can decide not to show the button and ask the user to enable 3rd party cookies.

Comment: What makes me really worried is that nobody reproduces this strong bug. Am I the only one with disabled 3d party cookies?

Comment: Such a low number of votes. Maybe we misconfigure something to hit this error? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=357625 seems relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to Python backend integration to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you please explain how you have solved that problem? i am getting same.

Comment: We are now using the Python integration instead of the Javascript integration, which is backend and therefore doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of depending on Google Signin library, you can test if third party cookies are disabled by youself, like: http://blog.jgc.org/2006/04/do-you-have-third-party-cookies.html

Comment: Agree, I'm checking if 3d party cookies are enabled, and show a warning if not.